# Angular: reset the form back to it´s original value after closing and reopening the modal

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, modal-dialog, reset

I have this problem - I have an items section - on the item click, there is a modal window opened with the possibility to edit text of the item inside textarea. However, when I edit the text and cancel/close the modal and then reopen again, the text is in the previously modified state. My goal is to reset the text to the correct existing state - so any update of the text before closing of the modal is removed.

Can you suggest some solution / function / link?

```
<form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="editItem()">
  <textarea rows="3" formControlName="text"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
  <button type="button" (click)="closeModal()">Close</button>
</form>
```

```
export class EditItemComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() item: Item;
  editForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.editForm = new FormGroup({
      text: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.editForm.controls.text.setValue(this.item.text);
  }

  editItem():void {
  //edit item logic
  }

  closeModal(): void {
    //logic for closing modal
    //here I know I can simply set the editForm text 
    //back to the original text but I want the general 
    //solution which will handle other possible scenarios - clicking away 
    //from modal closes the modal, pressing esc closes the modal ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the relevant sections of your code? Otherwise it's difficult to give you any (exact) answers. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for what you should include

Comment: Hi @Emma, thank you for your comment - I edited my question :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that when you edit the form when the modal is open, you're changing the value in the `text` field of the form. So if the modal is closed and opened again, the same current value in the `text` field is also present in the modal.

You could *either* place your entire form inside the modal itself so that the state is clean each time the modal is opened, *or* implement something similar to [Angular Material's `MatDialog`](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples).